# Magento 1.9 - Observer condition not working for Guest Customer

Tags: event-observer, magento1.9.2.3, guest-checkout, guest

My condition: Selected Payment Gateway Eligible only for a selected customer group, id 9.

My observer:

```
<?php
class Gta_FilterPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymenter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentCustomerGroup = (int)Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            if (($observer->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'paytm_cc') && ($currentCustomerGroup !== 9)) 
            {
                $result = $observer->getResult();
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i can set PayTM payment Gateway only for customer group 9, but guest customer also eligible to pay via PayTM payment gateway, how to restrict for guest customer also?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on magento 2.4 but I fixed it by using `HTTPcontext` instead of sessions. I don't know, for some reason sessions don't return expected customer group, probably some kind of cache issue. However, it works smoothly with `HTTPcontext`. But unfortunately, there's a difference in implementation of Magento1.x and Magento2.x. If you want, I can share 2.x code with you that uses dependency injection of `HTTPcontext` to get things done. :)

Comment: Yes, I did in Magento 2 - Code: https://paste.ofcode.org/f7ndd7CaQGsrSeGcciKzyd Now i am looking for Magento 1.

Comment: In your code on Magento 2, you've used `customerSession`, not `httpContext`. In my case, `customerSession` was returning customer_group_id of logged in customer, even when customer was logged out. I used `httpContext`, and this issue was resolved. I'd suggest you to check customer_group on different pages, and see if it's working fine, otherwise, perhaps, use `httpContext` not session.

Comment: Yes, i tested thoroughly even proxy browser its working, any help in Magento 1?

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: I just try to add is_logged_in so that its not applied for the guest customers right?

Comment: Yes, you need to check isLoggedIn() for guest customers, and look if it's returning expected results on every page i-e signup, signin, category to name the few.

Comment: The guest customer's group ID is 0, How to include in my if condition, my code :  https://paste.ofcode.org/aeK8CCgULkwreQbA6E6FDG My obsever working but working for the guest customer also, how to restrict?

Comment: There's no problem with your condition, it's a problem with `session` object since it doesn't return expected customer group on every page, what I said in my answer. That's why you need to `print_r($currentCustomerGroup);exit;` in your observer to see if it return `0` for logout customer or not. That's the only way to check if your `session` is working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following way ..

```
<?php 
//GET SESSION DATA
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->$session->id);

//CHECK IF LOGGED IN
if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    // here your logic
}
```

Comment: The guest customer's group ID is 0, in my code how can include in if condition if (($observer->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'paytm_cc') && ($currentCustomerGroup !== 9) && ($currentCustomerGroup == 0))   Not wokring. Any help thanks

Comment: My complete code: https://paste.ofcode.org/39vAiy2GEcAZQ8vkzEuSHGy   FYI My observer working but also working for Guest i want to restrict this.